# Как из командной строки осуществить открытие, чтение и запись в COM-порт Windows?

Tags: c#, cmd, wmi

У меня стоит задача мониторинга и управления ИБП АРС, подключенного к удаленной ПЭВМ через COM-порт RS232. Как работать с COM-портом на локальной ПЭВМ и осуществить мониторинг и управление ИБП АРС я знаю. А также я знаю как подключиться (через WMI или Telnet) к удаленной ПЭВМ и запустить и запустить задачу и исполнить её в консольном режиме. На удаленной ПЭВМ я не могу устанавливать своего ПО, т.е. мне необходимо пользоваться стандартными средствами Windows. А на ПЭВМ где производиться мониторинг (локальная) я хозяин, поэтому моя задача узнать как стандартными средствами Windows манипулировать COM-портом (а значит ИБП АРС) на удаленной ПЭВМ, а результаты получать и обрабатывать  на локальной ПЭВМ (где мониторинг).

Слышал я, что есть возможность удаленно манипулировать COM-портом можно через WMI, но я не знаю как.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413530. Я вам уже отвечал

Comment: На удаленную ПЭВМ я не могу устанавливать свои программы, поэтому я могу использовать только стандартные средства Windows!!!

Comment: Никак. Удалённый компьютер должен _сотрудничать_, то есть, там должна бежать либо ваша, либо ещё чья-то программа (по сути, сервер), которая по вашему запросу выполнит нужные действия.

Comment: Это не обязательно. Первый вариант: Можно подцепиться через WMI к удаленной ПЭВМ (предварительно запустив соответственную службу см. Попов  Андрей, Шикин Е. А  Администрирование Windows с помощью WMI и WMIC) и делать запросы WMI) а затем их обрабатывать на локальной ПЭВМ. Второй вариант: через Telnet и выполнять консольные команды(CMD)  и получать результаты  исполнения команд, а затем их обрабатывать на локальной ПЭВМ (предварительно запустив службу Сервер Telnet). Т.е. серверами на удаленной ПЭВМ будут Сервер WMI или Сервер Telnet!!!

Answer (score 4):

В командной строке Windows есть возможность обращаться к COM-порту по имени вида `COMx`, где `x` — номер порта. Эта возможность пришла ещё из MS DOS.

Например, для отправки текста «123» устройству можно воспользоваться командой

```
echo 123 > COM1
```

В порт будут отправлены байты, содержащие коды символов из параметра команды `echo`.

Для указания параметров порта можно воспользоваться командой `mode`. Пример использования:

```
mode COM1 BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8
```

Это означает, что порт COM1 работает со скоростью 9600 бод, передаёт данные по 8 бит и не использует проверку чётности.

Судя по тегам, вы можете использовать C#. В этом случае просто воспользуйтесь классом `SerialPort` из пространства имён `System.IO.Ports`. Однако этот класс позволяет работать с портом лишь на локальной машине.

Если вам требуется сложное поведение, то вы можете из командной строки удалённо создать файл с программой на C# и скомпилировать его утилитой csc.exe при условии, что на удалённой машине установлена платформа .NET (консольный компилятор входит в комплект её поставки).

Возможно есть и другие средства для удалённой работы с оборудованием машины, которые вам лучше подойдут. Например, если установлен PowerShell, то можно воспользоваться его возможностями.

Запись:

```
PS> [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()
COM3
PS> $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,9600,None,8,one
PS> $port.open()
PS> $port.WriteLine("Hello world")
PS> $port.Close()
```

Чтение:

```
PS> $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,9600,None,8,one
PS> $port.Open()
PS> $port.ReadLine()
```

Пример работы с портом из VBScript (к сожалению, не было возможности проверить на реальном железе).

Пример записи:

```
Dim port, fso
' Константы для режимов работы с файлом
Const ForAppending = 8
' Объект для работы с файлами
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Открываем порт для записи
Set port = fso.OpenTextFile("COM4:9600,N,8,1", ForAppending)
' Запись строки
port.Write "test" ' См. также WriteLine
' Закрываем порт
port.Close
```

Пример чтения:

```
Dim port, fso
' Константы для режимов работы с файлом
Const ForReading = 1
' Объект для работы с файлами
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Открываем порт для чтения
Set port = fso.OpenTextFile("COM4:9600,N,8,1", ForReading)
' Если не конец потока данных
if not port.AtEndOfStream then
    ' Выводим строку
    msgbox port.ReadAll ' См. также .Read и .ReadLine
end if
' Закрываем порт
port.Close
```

[Подробнее о работе с COM-портом из командной строки  (англ.)](https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/simple-trick-for-sending-characters-to-a-serial-port-in-windows/)

[Документация на класс SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: [Начиная с семёрки](http://serverfault.com/q/615275/137144), powershell по умолчанию инсталлирован в системе.

Comment: А не подскажите на чем лучше писать скрипты? На VBScript или JScript. У меня половина ПЭВМ под Windows XP.

Comment: Кстати, да! Я про них забыл совсем. Пишите на том языке, который вам ближе, разницы в возможностях никакой нет. Попробую набросать пример и дополню ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое за консультацию!!! Простите за наглость, а могли бы кинуть скрипт(PowerShell) как за Telnet’ится?!

Comment: Не за что! К сожалению, не могу. Я не эксперт в PowerShell, да и сейчас под рукой его нет. Просто раньше с портами приходилось иметь дело. Попробуйте задать ещё один вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

**Через WMI можно проверить открыт ли COM порт**

[WMI Explorer](https://wmie.codeplex.com/releases/view/135794) — Вот что может помочь для WMI. Важно понимать, что WMI доступен только при определенных условиях.

[Пример работы с WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32330/A-Useful-WMI-Tool-How-To-Find-USB-to-Serial-Adapto)

Стоит смотреть в сторону `\\.\ROOT\WMI\ms_409:MSSerial_CommInfo` там есть параметр `IsBusy`.

```
IsBusy - Boolean

   Qualifiers: CIMTYPE, Description, DisplayName

   The IsBusy property determines whether the serial port is busy
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую!!!